# How access the iframe elements from a java code

Tags: java, iframe, automated-tests

I need to access the value of div element inside an iframe from java code. The iframe is on a web browser and java code is on local server. I need this to test the values in iframe. I am new in coding/automation, any suggestion on how this can be done will be helpful. I found on net how to access through JS but i need to get the values in my java code. I am not using selenium web driver but original browser.

Any suggestion/pointer will be helpful, Thanks SOF!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have solution in JS then you can use the [Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

Below the basic example:

```
import javax.script.*;
public class EvalScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a script engine manager
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        // create a JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        // evaluate JavaScript code from String
        engine.eval("print('Hello, World')");
    }
}
```